# Cayley-Hamilton Theory [problem]

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

State the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, and verify it for the matrix
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 2 & -1\\
-6 & -1 & 2\\
7 & 2 & -2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I got the equation $x^3-5x^2+7x+27$
on replacing with matrix $A$, 
it becomes $A^3-5A^2+7A+27$.

I think there is no mistake on finding this eqn. the eqn may be right.
On solving eqn, I didn't get zero matrix.

Please solve the question may be  you can get zero matrix the

Comment: At least paste a decent version of the problem. As it is it's almost impossible to read.

Comment: looks like you are trying to cheat on an exam

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $p_A(\lambda) = -λ^3 + 3 λ^2 + λ - 3$.

Comment: @Mathematician why are you telling like that??i am preparing this one for my exam. if you dont wanna help then dont tell like that please

Comment: I'm not trying to be extra judgemental here. If you post a picture of one question on a piece of paper that looks taken as if noone was allowed to see you take that picture, it looks suspiscious. It wouldn't be the first time that happens on this site either. Anyway, don't take it too personal. The question as it's posed now is much better and will attract more positive attention.

Comment: "I think there is no mistake on finding this eqn. the eqn may be right. On solving eqn, I didn't get zero matrix." Since the CH theorem is _true_, you made a mistake somewhere in the calculations. You should  look at what you did and find the error yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ satisfies a monic polynomial equation given by
$$A^3-\operatorname{Trace}(A) A^2+ [A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}] A-\det |A| I= 0.$$
Here $\operatorname{Trace}(A) =a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}$. Here $a_{ii}$  denote  diagonal elements of $A$
and $A_{ii}$ denote the minors of the diagonal elements of $A.$  You may verify your answer like this also. In your case $\mbox{Trace}(A)=3, A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}=-1, \det |A|=-3$. So the cubic equation satisfied by $A$ is
$$A^3-3A^2-A+3I=0$$, the same as proposed by @Azif00

Comment: i have done this to find The characterstics equation  | A - λI |=0 and i got the eqn  x3−5x2+7x+27 . this is correct or not??

Comment: The eigen values of this matrix are $3,1,-1$ their sum is supposed to be equal to the Trace of the matrix the sum of their pairwise products is supposed to be equal to $A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}$. their product  equals  the determinant which is -3. So eventually the characteristic equation is $\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-\lambda+3=(\lambda-3)(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)=0$ ans so is the cubic of the matrix.